# Can you pin and move drone bodies like you can with guards?

Tags: invisible-inc

With guards, you can drag their bodies or keep them pinned to prevent them from reviving from a KO.

I assumed that you couldn't do the same thing with drones, since they're metal and heavy and aren't living.

Answer (score 2):

Pinning works exactly the same with drones as it does with humans. So if an agent is on the same square as them they will stay down indefinitely.

You can't drag drones so they will always stay on the square they were disabled on until they reboot.

It is worth noting that disabled drones don't block agent movement, even though it sometimes looks like they should

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pin drones to keep them from reviving from a KO. I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that you can't drag their bodies to hide them though.